# jkmount passes mount path to tomcat

Tags: apache, rest, tomcat, tomcat8, mod-jk

I'm using

```
JKMount        /rest/*    ajp13_worker
JKMount        /rest      ajp13_worker
```

to serve php at domain.com and my servlets at domain.com/rest/.
However, when i go to domain.com/rest/, it acts like i entered domain.com/rest/rest, so tomcat thinks i did go to /rest on tomcat but i want tomcat to think that I'm in the root directory. So i get a 404 Error because /rest/ obiously does not exist.
[image: 404 Error]

How can i get tomcat to think that I'm at root?
Thanks,
Niklas B.

Answer (score 1):

No, the ajp config is doing the exact thing it is meant to do.

When you map the requests with `JkMount` the AJP filter keeps the whole request path. So when you type `yourdomain.com/rest` or `yourdomain.com/rest/your_resource`, ajp is passing `/rest` or `/rest/your_resource` to Tomcat.

This way, it is easier to use the Tomcat's application context-path just as is in the Apache and AJP mappings. In this case, it should be easier to have the Tomcat application in context named '/rest'.

But when you have any other situation, there are other approaches, as, for example, `mod_proxy` or `mod_proxy_ajp`. Both ot them act as reverse proxy mapping the context-path `/rest` to tomcat but giving you the ability to change the request path of the request at the time of redirecting it to Tomcat. The difference between mod_proxy and mod_proxy_ajp is the fact that the first one uses the http port of Tomcat wilst the second one uses the ajp port.

The mappings should work this way:

```
ProxyPass /rest http://dns.ajp13_worker:8080/
ProxyPass /rest ajp://dns.ajp13_worker:8009/
```

Comment: when i use ProxyPass with ajp it causes the same problem, with http everything is ok. Is there any disadvantage when using http?

Comment: Sounds strange to me that ProxyPass ajp causes same problem, I have used several times this way... But anyway, I don't think there is any disadvantage for using http over ajp, I see more a kind of self preference.